# Passing data from child to parent, React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to pass data from a child component up to a parent component.  However, when doing so, I get the error:

`Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within render or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to componentWillMount`

I don't understand because when I use the same pattern with an event handler, everything is fine.  How can I successfully pass data from the child component to the parent without getting the error?

```js
const Child = (props) => {
  let message = 'Hi mom'
  props.callBackFromParent(message);
  return <h3>{props.message}</h3>
};

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      messageFromChild: '',
    }
    this.callBackFromParent = this.callBackFromParent.bind(this);
  }
  
  callBackFromParent(dataFromChild){
    this.setState({messageFromChild: dataFromChild})
  }
  
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Message from Child is:</h2>
       
        <Child 
          message={this.state.messageFromChild}
          callBackFromParent={this.callBackFromParent}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not to be rude but your question is kind of missing the point; it's like asking why it's ok to drive your car on the street but not ok to drive on the sidewalk. Defining a Component as just a function means that function *is* the `render` function. React is event based, and `render` isn't supposed to change state, that's just how it's designed.

Comment: To elaborate: React calls `render()` when the `state` changes, so if render calls caused state changes, you'd have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

It's not allowed to call `setState` during rendering, which a call to `props.callBackFromParent` would result in.

You can use the function as an event handler instead, and it will set the state of the parent as expected.

**Example**

```
const Child = (props) => {
  let message = 'Hi mom';

  return <h3 onClick={() => props.callBackFromParent(message)}>{props.message}</h3>
};
```